# Python program with main() method does not run

Tags: python

```
def main():
   names = []
   for line in ins:
       number_strings = line.split() # Split the line on runs of whitespace
       data.append(numbers_strings) # Add the "row" to your list.
       print(data)
```

I tried using this code to print a text file that looks like this

```
name num1 num2 C/N
```

I am trying to print this but when I run the command "python3 file.py" no output occurs. instead of printing the contents of the file I am putting in

Answer (score 6):

Unlike in C, execution in python does not begin from the `main` method, as python follows a top-down approach. What you'll need to do is explicitly *invoke* the `main` method to have it run.

```
def main():
    ...

main()
```

---

If you want the `main` method to run *only when invoked through the script* (and not when imported), specify under what `__name__` it should run:

```
def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For more information, read

- [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)
- [Understanding the main method of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492162/understanding-the-main-method-of-python)

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to execute that code you can forget about the main function and just write your code

```
names = []
   for line in ins:
       number_strings = line.split() # Split the line on runs of whitespace
       data.append(numbers_strings) # Add the "row" to your list.
       print(data)
```

If you do want to use a main function follow the community wiki answer.