# What is the difference between "main()" and "main(_)" in python?

Tags: python

I have seen some python code having "main(_)" function instead of "main()". What is the difference between these two main functions?

Comment: One takes an argument called `_`, the other doesn't. `main()` is not significant to python like it is in some other languages.

Comment: Refer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492162/understanding-the-main-method-of-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular significance to the `main` function in Python (unlike C, for example, where it's the entry point for hosted implementations).

You'll often see code in a module like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

so that running it and importing it will result in different behaviour. But there's nothing magical about the `main` name (or parameters that it takes), you could just as easily use:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xyzzy('plugh', 'twisty-passages')
```

In Python, the difference between `main()` and `main(_)` is that the latter takes a parameter called `_`. That's it, really.